# Is my intention pure

Tags: punishment

I suffer a lot from waswas but alhamdulillah through allahs help and guidance I am handling it . Today I had the intention of praying Quran to soften the hearts of the people around me through the beautiful words Of Allah. Whilst I was praying half way through  I suddenly got the intention to show them how “good my tajweed is “. And I then made sure I did the aeyn properly... but I repented straight away from that stupid intention .. will I be punished .!?? And is that pride ??? I read if you have pride you can’t enter jannah??

Comment: If you repented, then there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, everyone makes mistakes but best of them is the one who repents, Allah says in Quran:( tell them O Prophet (pbuh) ,"My servants who have been committed excesses against themselves (committed sins) do not lose hope in Allah's mercy. Surely Allah forgives all sins(with repentance) .He is the most forgiving most merciful.(39:53)